# How to update a cell in edit mode when updating another one in MUI Data Grid v6?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm using the MUI Data Grid v6 component and making use of its built-in CRUD editing feature. I have multiple columns, all of them editable. After selecting a new value in my column "category" of type `singleSelect`, this value should be pre-attached to the second column called "remark" which is of type `string`.

It's kind of easy to change the row model with `valueSetter` and `valueGetter`, but I didn't found a way to also change the "edit row model" and to apply the change directly to the input field.

[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Here's an extract of my current code:

```
const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'category',
    headerName: 'Category',
    type: 'singleSelect',
    flex: 2,
    editable: true,
    valueOptions: ['First', 'Second', 'Third'],
  },
  {
    field: 'remark',
    headerName: 'Remark',
    type: 'string',
    flex: 2,
    editable: true
  },
  {
    field: 'actions',
    headerName: 'Actions',
    type: 'actions',
    flex: 1,
    getActions: ({ id }) => { /*...*/ },
  },
];

// ...

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  editMode="row"
  rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
  onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
  onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
  processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
  slots={{
    toolbar: EditToolbar,
  }}
  slotProps={{
    toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It's great if you can answer this after solving

Comment: Have the exakt same issue with a nested object. valueGetter and valueSetter, as you said, doesn't cut it. @rockarolla do you still have no solution for this?

Comment: @Kryptor I posted my solution below as an answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think I've got a solution for this problem. Might be only for Pro licence though.

In my case I've got a nested object called "vehicle".

Start with creating a custom component that uses useGridApiContext(). I needed some default data to set if my singleSelect changes. So I'm adding a prop to GridEditSingleSelectCellProps.

```
type CustomTypeEditProps = GridEditSingleSelectCellProps & {
  vehicleTypes: VehicleType[]
}

const CustomTypeEditComponent = (props: CustomTypeEditProps) => {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext()

  const handleValueChange = async (_: SelectChangeEvent, newValue: string) => {
    const vehicleType = props.vehicleTypes.find(x => x.id === newValue)

    await apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id: props.id,
      field: 'vehicleWeight',
      value: vehicleType?.vehicleWeight
    })
    await apiRef.current.setEditCellValue({
      id: props.id,
      field: 'vehicleLength',
      value: vehicleType?.vehicleLength
    })
  }

  return (
    <GridEditSingleSelectCell onValueChange={handleValueChange} {...props} />
  )
}
```

Then you can use this component in the columns array. Something like this.

```
 [
    {
      field: 'vehicle',
      headerName: 'Vehicle',
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      valueSetter: vehicleDataSetter('articleId'),
      valueGetter ({ row }) {
        return row.vehicle.articleId
      },
      renderEditCell (params) {
        const customParams = { ...params, vehicleTypes }
        return <CustomTypeEditComponent {...customParams} />
      },
      valueOptions: vehicleTypes.map(v => ({
        value: v.id,
        label: v.id
      })),
      type: 'singleSelect'
    },
    {
      field: 'vehicleWeight',
      headerName: 'Weight',
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      type: 'number',
      valueGetter (params) {
        return params.row.vehicle.weight
      },
      valueSetter: vehicleDataSetter('weight')
    },
    {
      field: 'vehicleLength',
      headerName: 'Length',
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
      type: 'number',

      valueGetter (params) {
        return params.row.vehicle.length
      },
      valueSetter: vehicleDataSetter('length')
    },
 ]
```

I have a function for handling setting the selected data in each prop in the nested object.

```
 const vehicleDataSetter =
   (key: string) => (params: GridValueSetterParams) => {
     return {
       ...params.row,
       vehicle: {
         ...params.row.vehicle,
         [key]: params.value
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try implementing that logic in [`processRowUpdate`](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/editing/#the-processrowupdate-callback) callback?

There you can compare the updated with the original row and apply the necessary changes

```
<DataGrid
 processRowUpdate={(updatedRow, originalRow) => {
  if (updatedRow.category !== originalRow.category) {
   return {
    ...updatedRow,
    remark: `${updatedRow.category} FILL_MORE`
   }
  }
  return  updatedRow
 }}
/>
```

Please note that the remark field will change only after you exit the edit mode of the category field

Answer (score 0):

Here my own - rather ugly - solution to the problem. It's not pretty, but in the end it is working as expected. Maybe it can help someone with a similar issue.

For the edit cells I'm using an `Autocomplete` and a custom component called `ValidatableEditInputCell`, but it should work with any other component as well.

I created the variable `remarkPreset` to shortly/temporarily save the value of my category field once the input has changed. When a value of a cell is changed, all `preProcessEditCellProps` callbacks from all cells are called. That's the point, where I read the preset value and set it to the remark field via `params.props.value = remarkPreset.value;`.

Oh, and I'm also not prepending but replacing the value, but that can be changed easily.

```
let remarkPreset: { id: GridRowId; value: string } | undefined;

const columns: GridColDef[] = [
  {
    field: 'category',
    headerName: 'Category',
    flex: 2,
    editable: true,
    renderEditCell: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => {
      <Autocomplete
        //...
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          remarkPreset = {
            id: params.id,
            value: newValue.category,
          };
          focusCell(params.id.toString(), 'remark');
        }}
      />
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'remark',
    headerName: 'Remark',
    flex: 2,
    editable: true,
    preProcessEditCellProps: async (params: GridPreProcessEditCellProps) => {
      if (remarkPreset && remarkPreset.id === params.id) {
        params.props.value = remarkPreset.value;
      }
      return { ...params.props, error: false };
    },
    renderEditCell: (params: GridRenderEditCellParams) => {
      if (
        remarkPreset != undefined &&
        remarkPreset.id === params.id &&
        remarkPreset.value === params.value
      ) {
        remarkPreset = undefined;
      }

      return (
        <ValidatableEditInputCell
          {...params}
          maxLength={40}
          defaultValue={remarkPreset?.id === params.id ? remarkPreset.value : undefined}
        />
      );
    },
  },
  {
    field: 'actions',
    headerName: 'Actions',
    type: 'actions',
    flex: 1,
    getActions: ({ id }) => { /*...*/ },
  },
];

const focusCell = (id: string, field: string) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const input = document.querySelector(
      `div.MuiDataGrid-row[data-id="${id}"] div[data-field="${field}"] input`
    ) as HTMLInputElement;
    input.focus();
  }, 50);
};

<DataGrid
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  editMode="row"
  rowModesModel={rowModesModel}
  onRowModesModelChange={handleRowModesModelChange}
  onRowEditStop={handleRowEditStop}
  processRowUpdate={processRowUpdate}
  slots={{
    toolbar: EditToolbar,
  }}
  slotProps={{
    toolbar: { setRows, setRowModesModel },
  }}
/>
```